# Show that $|z_1 + z_2|^2 < (1+C)|z_1|^2 + \left(1 + \frac{1}{C}\right) |z_2|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

> Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two complex numbers. Show that there exists $C > 0$ with
>   $$
>  |z_1 + z_2|^2 < (1+C)|z_1|^2 + \left(1 + \frac{1}{C}\right) |z_2|^2.
> $$

I tried to simplify the L.H.S and R.H.S, SNF I was finally left to compare between a real number and a complex number 
I really couldn't think of anything else. Please help.

Comment: $z_1 = z_2 = c = 1$ gives $4 < 4$, so probably the inequality should be $\leq$ instead of $<$ or $c \neq 1$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The given inequality can be rewritten as the obvious inequality

$$\left|\sqrt{c}z_1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}z_2\right|^2\ge 0$$

Comment: I don't understand this .. Can you please explain

Comment: @Tejus: Just multiply both inequalities out and check that they're equivalent.

Comment: Got it!!! thanksss

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\lvert z_1+ z_2\rvert^2 +\lvert z_1 - z_2\rvert^2=2\lvert z_1\rvert^2 +2\lvert z_2\rvert^2. $$